What does Baldwin mean by the "racial value" of nonviolence?
Implicitly contrasting the strategies of the Nation of Islam to those of Martin Luther King, Jr, James Baldwin writes:

The real reason that nonviolence is considered to be a virtue in Negroes—I am not speaking now of its racial value, another matter altogether—is that white men do not want their lives, their self-image, or their property threatened.
Baldwin, James. "Down at the Cross: Letter from a Region of my Mind." 1962. The Fire Next Time. 1963. New York: Modern Library, 1995. pp. 13–105. Quotation is from pp. 58–59. 

I am not sure I understand the clause set off by the em dashes. If it were not for the term "racial," I would assume Baldwin is saying that he is discussing only the fact that nonviolence is considered morally sound, and not opining on its effectiveness as a strategy. But the adjective "racial," rather than "tactical" or even "social," gives me pause. What does Baldwin mean by the "racial value" of nonviolence?
